# AWS - SAM cli yaml template does not work with cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I'm having a problem with aws CloudFormation…
I guess as I'm new I'm missing something…

So I installed sam cli on my mac and it generated this .yaml file
then I go to cloud formation and try to upload this file to a stack

during creation it gives me an error:

```
Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless 
Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Resource 
with id [HelloWorldFunction] is invalid. 'CodeUri' is not a valid S3 Uri 
of the form 's3://bucket/key' with optional versionId query parameter.. 
Rollback requested by user.
```

What should I do here ?
I'm trying to create a lambda function with trigger on s3 file upload and I need an .yaml file for CloudFormation to describe all the services and triggers… I found it extremely difficult to find a template which works…

How should I try to fix this ? when even cli generated yaml files don't work ?
Shouldn't CloudFormation initialize a lambda function when there no such function created yet?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the template?

Comment: I can not post it here, string is too long… It is basic template which comes with sam cli hello-world app

Comment: Perhaps review of some of the official AWS tutorials on www.serverlessland.com there are also lots of patterns there you can just grab the SAM templates and build/ package & deploy whatever you want should help you get started

Answer (score 0):

The templates that AWS SAM uses are more flexible than those that can be interpreted by AWS CloudFormation. The problem you're running into here is that AWS SAM can handle relative paths on your file system as a CodeUri for your lambda function, CloudFormation however expects an S3 uri in order to retrieve the function code to upload to the lambda.

You should have a look at the [`sam package`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-package.html) command. This command will resolve all sam specific things (e.g., it will upload the code to S3 and replace the CodeUri in the template). And create a "packaged template" file that you will be able to upload to CloudFormation.

You can also use the `sam deploy` command, which will package the template and deploy it to cloudformation itself.